# string concat C, any better solution?

Tags: c, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

This is a code snippet for concatenating strings. The code has to be designed so that,
one function will be there to form a payload and that function will be called again and again passing some arguments to it. Thus at end it will create one final payload. Also after each call there should be one `','` which will be added to string on each call of function but not at the last call.
Example : calling function 3 times

```
    form_payload (sensor_name1, sensor_val1);
    form_payload (sensor_name2, sensor_val2);
    form_payload (sensor_name3, sensor_val3);
```

Output:

```
Final Payload : sense1;title="12",sense2;title="14",sense3;title="23"
```

Here is the code snippet :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char final_payload[1024];
char temp_payload[128];
char sensor_name1 [15];
char sensor_val1 [4];

void form_payload(char *pl_1, char *pl_2) {

    memset (temp_payload, '\0', strlen(temp_payload));
    sprintf(temp_payload, "%s;title=\"%s\",", pl_1, pl_2);
    strcat(final_payload, temp_payload);
    memset (temp_payload, '\0', strlen(temp_payload));
}

void main() {

    memset (final_payload, '\0', strlen(final_payload));
    memset (sensor_name1, '\0', strlen(sensor_name1));
    memset (sensor_val1, '\0', strlen(sensor_val1));
    sprintf(sensor_name1, "sense1");
    sprintf(sensor_val1, "12");
    form_payload (sensor_name1, sensor_val1);
    form_payload (sensor_name1, sensor_val1);
    printf("\nFinal Payload : %s\n", final_payload);
}
```

Currently this will append a comma even at final call which I don't want. I can handle it like adding extra param as a comma to argument to function.
Can anyone suggest a better approach to do that?

Comment: `memset (final_payload, '\0', strlen(final_payload));` is actually ineffective

Comment: @SouravGhosh any suggestion on the problem ?

Comment: @Zim, you can use `memset (temp_payload, '\0', sizeof(temp_payload));`

Comment: on a computer that is running a OS, there are only two valid and one optional way of writing the signature for the main() function.  they all have a return type of 'int'.

Comment: the code fails to check that there is enough room left in the `final_payload[]` array to hold the string in 'temp_payload[]` array.   So the final_payload[] array can be overflowed, resulting in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: Why do you use globals (which are automatically zero-filled), then zero-fill them explicitly, only to overwrite their content with some constant string? Also, why do you think you need to concatenate the strings if all you do is output them? Or is that just for demonstration purposes?

Answer (score 2):

For starters it is a bad idea to use global variables in a function. In this case the function will depand on specific names and there may be a name collision in the program.

Also there is no need to use memset each time the function is called.

Take into account that according to the C Standard function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

The function could be written the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * form_payload( char *dest, const char *title, const char *value ) 
{
    size_t n = strlen( dest );

    if ( n )
    {
        dest[n++] = ',';
        dest[n] = '\0';
    }

    sprintf( dest + n, "%s;title=\"%s\"", title, value );

    return dest;
}

int main( void )
{
    char final_payload[1024];
    final_payload[0] = '\0';

    puts( form_payload( final_payload, "sense1", "12" ) );

    puts( form_payload( final_payload, "sense2", "14" ) );
}
```

Its output is

```
sense1;title="12"
sense1;title="12",sense2;title="14"
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char final_payload[1024];
char temp_payload[128];
char sensor_name1 [15];
char sensor_val1 [4];

void form_payload(char *pl_1, char *pl_2) {

    if(!strlen(final_payload))
        sprintf(temp_payload, "%s;title=\"%s\"\0", pl_1, pl_2);
    else
        sprintf(temp_payload, ",%s;title=\"%s\"\0", pl_1, pl_2);
    strcat(final_payload, temp_payload);
}

int main(void) {

    memset (final_payload, '\0', sizeof(final_payload));
    memset (sensor_name1, '\0', sizeof(sensor_name1));
    memset (sensor_val1, '\0', sizeof(sensor_val1));
    sprintf(sensor_name1, "sense1");
    sprintf(sensor_val1, "12");
    form_payload (sensor_name1, sensor_val1);
    form_payload (sensor_name1, sensor_val1);
    printf("\nFinal Payload : %s\n", final_payload);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no `void main(){}` you should use at least `int main(void){}` If you post an Answer at least you can take care about this problem and only after that you should say: `What about this solution?`

Comment: @Michi In which environment would this cause a problem?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider in an environment where people think that compiler warnings are problems to be solved.

Comment: @marcolz That problem is easily soved with "Wno-main" ;-). Do you know of an enviroment in which declaring `main` `void` would cause problems beyond compiler warnings? I'm genuinely curious. I can of course imagine certain kinds of runtime problems but I'm not aware of an operating system/C runtime where they occur.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider The program that forked to start your program may wait() for the return value to do something with it. It is common practice to exit() or return from main with a non-0 value. Declaring main as void robs you of the latter option so if you do not use exit(), you will return an undefined value.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider There is no need for explanation, read the standard. Starting with `C99` the return statement `return 0;` is no needed anymore because it is implicit. Being implicit means that return's type of `main` is int. Also you should know, that the return type of `main()` must always be an int, this allows a return code to be passed to the invoker. So Yes `void main(){}` **is wrong**.

Comment: @Michi Everything you say is true (except "no need for exaplanation" which is by default false), but it doesn't answer my question. I googled a bit and was astonished how hard it is to find something which could go wrong (besides the obviously arbitrary program exit code). The most serious complication is an ABI which puts return values in registers. I assume that the run time could trap when reading the uninitialized register (the same reason which makes reading uninitialized variables UB).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I do not have to explain you that, if you ask something like that. That's the whole point :) I did Answered your Question, but you didn't understood my point.

Comment: Just because Void means 0 in `C` it doesn't mean that  `void main(){}`  means that return type value is always 0. By the way `void min(){}` it is only used by Microsoft Windows base compiler’s.

Comment: To answer to your Question: `In which environment would this cause a problem`  ==>> In `C` will do it at some point.

Comment: @Michi The arbitrary return value is obvious but not a showstopper. The only (!) demonstration of an ill effect I could find is in https://www.ty-penguin.org.uk/~auj/voidmain/ where the author demonstrates OS errors on ARM when an application returns with exit codes > `Sys$RCLimit`. Note that it's not the `void main()` per se but an illegal exit code which of course could also be returned the proper way that causes the trouble. One must in general avoid illegal exit codes, and returning with arbitrary ones is just a special way to make that error.

Comment: Like i said `void main(){}` it is only used by Microsoft Windows base compiler’s and shouldn't be used.

Comment: I had just copy and paste the source from the TO. I could not imagine, that it would start just a big discussion here, especially because this has nothing to do with the TO's problem. But  I have edited my answer, only to make Michi sleep well ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, your attempts to zero the buffers with memset warrant a discussion because their intent is clear (and laudable) but they are bogous on a number of levels.

- Globals are zeroed anyway, so the memset is unncecessary in `main()`;
- the zeroing includes the first byte so that strlen() always returned 0, so in `main()` no memory is actually ever set -- but that didn't hurt ;-);
- thinking about it, we don't need them zeroed at all for a successful sprintf()! :-) That includes the calls in `form_payload()`.

Second, I would avoid repeated `strlen()` calls for strings whose length is known, and keep a current position instead. For short strings and low numbers of function calls it shouldn't matter. But from a general point of view strlen() makes the time complexity quadratic for a problem of linear complexity, which just seems wrong.

Now to my suggestions.

I'd make two distinct functions, along the lines of `strcpy()` and `strcat()`, one for just writing a payload and one for appending one. The appending one *prepends* a comma and then calls the write function. Both functions operate on a parameter for the destination (so they know nothing about the global buffer and you are free to change it or reuse the functions elsewhere). They also return a pointer to the next writing destination, which is the address of the 0 byte at the end of the last written string.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char final_payload[1024];
char temp_payload[128];
char sensor_name1 [15];
char sensor_val1 [4];

char *write_payload(char *dest, char *pl_1, char *pl_2) {
    // sprintf returns the number of bytes written. Adding that to
    // the destination address gives the new writing destination.
    return dest + sprintf(dest, "%s;title=\"%s\"", pl_1, pl_2);
}

// Write a comma and then call the write function with the 
// position after the comma.
char *append_payload(char *dest, char *pl_1, char *pl_2) {
    *dest++ = ',';
    return write_payload(dest, pl_1, pl_2);
}

int main() {

    // The current write position in the payload string. Starts at 
    // the beginning of the buffer and is incremented by the number
    // of bytes written in each sprintf.
    char *curr_pos = final_payload;

    curr_pos = write_payload(curr_pos, "sense1", "12");
    curr_pos = append_payload(curr_pos, "sense2", "22");
    curr_pos = append_payload(curr_pos, "sense3", "32");


    printf("\nFinal Payload: ->%s<-\n", final_payload);

    // You could even nest the calls, the same way you can nest
    // strcats. The first parameter of the two
    // outer calls, the destination, 
    // is the return value of the respective next inner call. 
    // The innermost call is completed first, and then so on 
    // winding outward, so we must have the first call -- 
    // write_payload -- inside.
    append_payload
    (   append_payload
        (   write_payload
            (   final_payload, 
                "senseA", 
                "A"
            ), 
            "senseB", 
            "B"
        ), 
        "senseC", 
        "C"
    );

    printf("\nFinal Payload: ->%s<-\n", final_payload);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample session:

```
$ gcc -Wall -o payload payload.c && ./payload

Final Payload: ->sense1;title="12",sense2;title="22",sense3;title="32"<-

Final Payload: ->senseA;title="A",senseB;title="B",senseC;title="C"<-
```